# Get specific parent of an element

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm using this code to get overlay on hover on all elements in one ".grid", except one that is hovered:

```
var galleryGrid = $('.grid'),
    galleryImg = $('a.img-to-bg'),
    galleryImgOverlay = $('.overlay-wrapper');
// Overlay on hover gallery
galleryImg.on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).find(galleryImgOverlay).addClass('hovered');
        //$(this).parentsUntil(galleryGrid).parent().find(galleryImgOverlay).not('.hovered').css({
        $(this).parents('.grid').find(galleryImgOverlay).not('.hovered').css({
            'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
        });
        return false; 
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).find(galleryImgOverlay).removeClass('hovered');
        //$(this).parentsUntil(galleryGrid).parent().find(galleryImgOverlay).css({
        $(this).parents('.grid').find(galleryImgOverlay).css({
            'background': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        });
        return false; 
    }
});
```

So, my question is: What is proper way to get specific parent?

I found two ways to do it:

```
$(this).parents('.grid').find(galleryImgOverlay).css({

$(this).parentsUntil(galleryGrid).parent().find(galleryImgOverlay).css({
```

And, when I use var galleryGrid in first example, console.log prints out as same as if I wrote just parents(). Why is that?

This is html code:

```
<!-- Section Content -->
<div class="container margintop80">

    <!-- List of Galleries -->
    <ul class="grid">

        <!-- Gallery A -->
        <li class="toAnimateToo">

            <a href="..." class="img-to-bg">
                <div class="overlay-wrapper">
                    <div class="overlay-inner">
                        <div class="center">
                            <div class="btn btn-full-full"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no need to bubble to parent just use `.find()` since `overlay-wrapper` is child of the a

Comment: `$(this).closest(".grid")` https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @guradio I have multiple galleries in one grid, and I need to get all overlay-wrappers in all galleries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it isnt a direct parent I would use `closest()` to travels up the DOM tree and return the first (single) ancestor that matches the passed expression:

```
$(this).closest('.grid').find(galleryImgOverlay).css({
```

Comment: Yeah, this works too. I'm just curious, is this considered to be the best way to get specific parent?

Comment: If you want the direct parent you could use one of this trasversing ancestors: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_ancestors.asp if isnt direct parent better use closest()

Comment: Thank you! And one last question: Why this: "$(this).parents('.grid').find(galleryImgOverlay).css({" doesn't work same as this: "$(this).parents(galleryGrid).find(galleryImgOverlay).css({"?

Comment: Where is located $('a.img-to-bg') in the html tag?

Comment: On a tag, I removed class for this example, my bad.

Comment: I dont know, apparently are exactly the same except that one selector is used as variable.

Comment: Yea. Only difference is that in first example console.log returns that specific element with class .grid, while second example returns every parent of "$(this)".